# Как можно считывать несколько клавиш одновременно в консоли?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Здравствуйте. Как можно считывать несколько клавиш одновременно в консоли? Это нужно для игры. Одними клавишами управляется первый персонаж, другими - второй.

Comment: Правильный ответ - никак. А почему нужно именно одновременно? И с какой временной точностью одновременно?

Comment: @rishat, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Создайте обработчик в отдельном потоке. Ему передавайте все нажатые клавиши. В зависимости от того, какая клавиша нажата, действие делает либо один, либо другой персонаж.